# I want to add new template when I click on shipment button

Tags: magento2

I want to add new template when I click on shipment button. 
Please anyone can help me here, I am new in magento. Thank you

Comment: For backend side?

Comment: Email template?

Comment: for backend side.

Comment: I think I have to override the controller